# how to display byte[] as picture in html with java

Tags: javascript, java, html, image, file

I use spring mvc and JPA in my project. I get file as `byte[]` and save in Database. but when I want to display in `<img` tag of html it don't display.

my entity is:

```
class Photo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @Lob
    private byte[] profilePic;

    // getter and setter
}
```

value in Database is:
[image]

but my server response is:
[image]

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "pic 1",
    "profilePic": "ZGF0YTppb...VFtQ0M=",
}
```

and display in html:

```
<img src='ZGF0YTppb...VFtQ0M=' />
//or
<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,ZGF0YTppb...VFtQ0M=' />
```

What to do to display the photo?

thanks

Comment: Is the value of the src attribute the byte array encoded in Base 64? This is not how the browser interprets your src tag. It must be a URL. You can use a controller to resolve the URL to file bytes from the database.

Comment: hello @RaviGupta,  I displayed the profilePic field values in the database, backend and frontend.

Comment: The value in your database *is* already a `data:` URI, so don’t try to encode it again.

Comment: I don't use any encoding really

Comment: Well, somehow, your database value, `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw…` became `data:image/jpeg;base64,ZGF0YTp…`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't use encode

Comment: Your question shows a Java class, JSON data, and HMTL. *Somehow*, these three things are linked and you should know, how. You didn’t even name the frameworks in use, forcing us to do guesswork. E.g., what happens when you change the type of `profilePic` (and associated getter and setter) to `String`? Does the framework pass the data as-is then, rather than base64 encoded?

Comment: I sayed to use spring mvc and jpa. I get json from js and without any encode set data in my object as byte[] and I saved my object in oracle db with JPA. You can question from me too

Comment: Well, you didn’t answer the most important question. What happens when you just declare `profilePic` as `String` (because what you showed as database contents, `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw…` *is* a string). The reason you see `[100, 97, 116, 97, 58, 105…` when inspecting the data in the Java runtime is because that’s what you can expect when inspecting a variable of type `byte[]`. The framework used to export the byte array as JSON apparently decided to use base64 encoding for `byte[]`. It surely wouldn’t do that if the property had a string type. Using a string type could solve all problems…

Comment: type of database is a blob, I downloaded value of blob to display. I only call ```entityManager.persist(photo);``` to save object. and type of ```profilePic``` is ```byte[]``` in backend. I don't change data or even type of ```profilePic```. Everything is done automatically really

Comment: Well, you will never know if you don’t try it. I don’t know whether the framework would do the conversion of a blob to string correctly, but on the other hand, I don’t use such tools which do “everything automatically” the wrong way. Still, there is a high chance that using a string at this place would do. Of course, you could instead leave everything as-is, then you have to live with the unnecessary base64 encoding. When you decode the `'ZGF0YTppb...VFtQ0M='` string on the Javascript side, like `atob('ZGF0YTppb...VFtQ0M=')` you also get the correct `data:` URI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's base64 encoded:

`<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,ZGF0YTppb...VFtQ0M=' />`

Basically you can use data urls with this format depending on what content [type] you want to display:

`data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>`

Comment: hi thanks a lot, I have used this method before but that didn't work

Comment: then try converting byte[] to base64 string

Comment: can I do something in javascript instead of java?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<img id="profileImg" src="">
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("profileImg").src = "data:image/png;base64," + profilePic;
```

This assumes that your image is stored in PNG format (and base64 encoded). For other image format (JPEG, etc.), you need to change the MIME type ("image/..." part) in the URL.